# Is this a bug or a feature: Community Mod Auto Flag?

Tags: bug

Auto Comment demanding code.
[How do liberal Protestants reconcile support for transgenderism with scripture?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/56501/how-do-liberal-protestants-reconcile-support-for-transgenderism-with-scripture/84779#comment236676_84779)

> Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working
> code or documentation citations. –  Community♦  24 mins ago

When I flagged it a red text box said it would be removed when the post was corrected, so, I edited the answer (format and quote block) to help this thing go away but **it did not**.

I think that at RPGSE the mods were able to prevail upon the PTB to get rid of this.

Can we get this removed also?

Comment: It's part of a [very flawed update to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/256282). Those comments cannot even be deleted by mods!

Comment: Aah, thanks @curiousdannii, I guess the never ending "improvement" to the review queues (which makes them clunky to use) continues.

Comment: I like the idea of a lot of the changes. But the implementation has been very poor.

Comment: [Looks like RPGSE did not get it fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369067/380710) @curiousdannii

Comment: They've fixed it so that we can at least delete the comments now.